# Как через CLI задать параметры из php.ini

Tags: php, .htaccess, кодировка, php.ini, консоль

PHP скрипт запускаю через CLI.

Пытаюсь установить значения: `mbstring.internal_encoding=UTF-8` и `mbstring.func_overload=2`

Делаю это так:

```
set_ini("mbstring.internal_encoding", "UTF-8");
set_ini("mbstring.func_overload", "2");
```

Далее пытаюсь пытаюсь обрезать строку и вывести результат:

```
$str = "Строка";
echo substr($str, 1);
```

Скрипт ничего не выводит..

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема? уже везде пишу, никто не может помочь или подсказать..

А задача у меня в следующем:
нужно при запуске скрипта из консоли, чтобы функции strpos, substr, strlen и т.д. могли работать с кириллицей.

Comment: А какая версия PHP? mbstring.internal_encoding Устарела с PHP 5.6.0.   также mbstring.func_overload  можно менять PHP_INI_SYSTEM  - "Значение может быть установлено в php.ini или httpd.conf" то есть в скрипте это не установить. Ну и вывод ошибок тоже включите в скрипте, для отладки

Comment: `php -v` показывает версию 5.3.

Если запускаю скрипт через браузер все прекрасно работает.

Мне нужно запустить некий скрипт из cli, который использует методы ядра CMS.

В этих методах используются функции strpos/substr/...  исменить их к сожалению я не могу.

Но нужно как-то сделать, чтобы эти функции из консольного режима работали с кириллицей правильно.

Я так понял, настройки для этих функций установлены в .htaccess
`mbstring.internal_encoding=UTF-8
mbstring.func_overload=2`

но при запуске скрипта из cli он не учитывает же .htaccess ?

Comment: Первую настройку для 5.3 можно сделать из скрипта, а вот вторую только в "Значение может быть установлено в php.ini или httpd.conf"  - для консоли. Возможно у вас php.ini разный для консоли и веб сервера.